# How to modify python bytecode to print something after execution

Tags: python, bytecode

I want to use [pyspy](https://github.com/bereal/pyspy) to generate DSL to get a sequence diagram with [ZenUML](https://app.zenuml.com/)

But my understanding of bytecode is poor. I already read most of the questions and answers tagged with bytecode and python in SO.
I'm playing with [byteplay](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ByteplayDoc) and some easy functions to understand what happens.

My goal was to write something before a call and write something after a call. I think I'll get it to work putting a try/finally block surrounding the functions like done here (have not tried it yet, but seems to be a better solution):
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577283-decorator-to-expose-local-variables-of-a-function-/

But I want to understand why my first approach to append code to recursive functions don't work.

This is what I did:

```py
from byteplay import *

### Some functions to play with...
def hello():
    print "hello!"

def easy(a):
    x = a*2
    print "easy: %s x 2 = %s" % (a, x)
    return x

def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)

# for f in (hello, easy, factorial):
#     c = Code.from_code(f.func_code)
#     print '---- code: ----'
#     print c.code
# print "*"*70

def add_hello_bye(fun):
    'Modifies the code of the given function to say hello + bye.'
    c = Code.from_code(fun.func_code)
    #print '---- org code: ----'
    #print c.code

    #hello_code = Code.from_code(hello.func_code).code[1:4]
    hello_code = [(LOAD_CONST, 'hello!'),
                  (PRINT_ITEM, None),
                  (PRINT_NEWLINE, None),
                 ]
    bye_code   = [(LOAD_CONST, 'bye!'),
                  (PRINT_ITEM, None),
                  (PRINT_NEWLINE, None)
                 ]
    c.code[0:0] = hello_code
    c.code.extend(bye_code)
    #print '---- new code: ----'
    #print c.code

    fun.func_code = c.to_code()

### Apply to easy:
add_hello_bye(easy) 
print '---- easy: ----'
print easy(4)

### Apply to factorial:
add_hello_bye(factorial) 
print '---- factorial: ----'
factorial(4)
```

First I had `c.code[-1:-1] = bye_code` and I thought the cause was that `RETURN_VALUE` has to be the last instruction, but putting the code at the end works for my simple function `easy` why not for recursive function `factorial`.

EDIT: I already tried `sys.settrace` and I have an alternative working solution using it.

Comment: we have Java implementation for the converter which you may want to have a look. This is not going to help with this question though. Check it out at - https://github.com/ZenUml/jetbrains-zenuml

Comment: Your `factorial()` function contains two `return`s.  Bytecode inserted just before the end of the function isn't going to be executed if the first `return` was taken.  You would need to scan the bytecode and insert your modifications before *every* `RETURN_VALUE` (and it still wouldn't be executed if the function ended via an uncaught exception).

Comment: @jasonharper: Ok, I understand the problem. So the solution using try/finally would handle both: more than one `RETURN_VALUE` and also exceptions. Thank you!